# Google Analytics data loss in custom reports dimention drilldowns

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to build custom report in Google Analytics using Flat Table Type and Dimension as County -> City -> Age.
Full custom report configuration in image below.
[image]
But I guess the resulting report is dropping lot of traffic as I definitely get lot of traffic from all over the world (I can see it if I look at it as single dimension e.g traffic by country etc) but in the resulting report only few countries show up.See resulting report below.
[image]
Why is this happening?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using age. When the demographic dimensions are used, and they become too specific (to the point where you might be able to identify an individual) Google masks the data.